# ShowDialog() is not preventing the originating form from being clickable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have a winform with the following code that opens an external program when the form is opened. If the program closes, a dialog box is suppose to pop up with an option to return that a button was clicked. This will close the dialog box and return to the initial form and then run the function to open the external program again.

Here is the problem, the original form is STILL clickable AND the function is not running. Any ideas?

```
    public Manager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ExternalProgramOpen();

    }

    private void ExternalProgramOpen()
    {
        Process startProgram = Process.Start("program.exe", Program.ConnectionArg);
        startProgram.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        startProgram.Exited += this.PrematureClose;
    }

    private void PrematureClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManagerWarning messagepopup = new ManagerWarning();
        messagepopup.ShowDialog();
        using (var ManagerWarning = new ManagerWarning())
        {
            if (ManagerWarning.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                ExternalProgramOpen();
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Never display UI on a worker thread, lots of nasty problems with that beyond dialogs not being modal.  Simple workaround is adding `startProgram.SynchronizingObject = this;`

Comment: I'm not even sure if your `PrematureMethod` should even compile. Are you sure the code you've posted is the one your running? You are creating and showing two consecutive modal dialogs, one outside the `using` statement and another one inside using the class name as the instance name...your doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: It compiled just fine. Now with the addition of the `invoke` code it does what it is suppose to do (except the part with the dialog box button being clicked).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this effect is probably that the `Exited` event is not raised in the same UI thread that started the process.

When you call `ShowDialog()` from another thread, the new window will not use and block the original UI thread.

To solve this, check if [`InvokeRequired`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx) is `true` and use [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void PrematureClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => PrematureClose(sender, e)));
        return;
    }

    // your code here
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The form is not only not in the same thread, it's *not even in the same process*

Comment: @Servy may I misunderstand OP's question, but to me it seems the _other_ process already exited and he is opening a new form in his original process. So the forms he's talking about seem to be in the same original process, not the exited one.

Comment: @René Vogt Thanks sooo much!! My Dialog box is properly keeping the original form from being clicks. Only problem now is my code to run the `ExternalProgramOpen()` function is not working.

Comment: @DavidBentley what does "not working" mean? maybe it's a new question...

Comment: @René Vogt I should probably ask in another question, but essentially, I need the dialog to pop up, a button is clicked, that dialog closes, and the `ExternalProgramOpen()` function from above needs to run again.

Comment: @DavidBentley you open _two_ dialogs: `messagepopup` and `ManagerWarning`.... and each blocks execution until it's closed again. `ExternalProgramOpen` is only called if `ManagerWarning` is closed with `DialogResult.Retry`... try to debug what happens there...